# How can I create a procedure from a long command in R?

Tags: r, command

I have a command with six lines that I want to use several times. Therfore, I want to assign a name to this command and use it as a procedure instead of writing the whole command lines over and over.

In this case it is a `<-rbind()` command, but the issue is also more general.

```
modelcoeff<-rbind(modelcoeff,c(as.character((summary(mymodel)$terms[[2]])[[3]]),
          as.character((((((summary(mymodel)$terms[[2]])[[2]])[[3]])[[3]])[[2]])[[3]]),
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,1],
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,4],
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,2],
          summary(mymodel)$r.squared*100))
```

I would like to call something like `rbindmodelcoeff` and execute these command lines. How can I achieve this?
I tried to write a function, but it didn't seem to be the right approach.

Comment: The function approach seems to be the correct way : what did you try and why didn't it give you the expected results?

Comment: I created a function with rbindmodelcoeff<-function(){my command lines} but this function did not execute the rbind. I thought that the output of a function is a value as I saw in several examples. But I need a simple procedure, like I know it from different programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal wrapping of your code into a function:

```r
rbindmodelcoeff <- function(modelcoeff, mymodel) {
  rbind(modelcoeff,
        c(as.character((summary(mymodel)$terms[[2]])[[3]]),
          as.character((((((summary(mymodel)$terms[[2]])[[2]])[[3]])[[3]])[[2]])[[3]]),
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,1],
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,4],
          summary(mymodel)$coefficients[2,2],
          summary(mymodel)$r.squared*100))
}
```

However, there are a couple changes I recommend:

- call `summary(mymodel)` *once*, then re-use the results
- you are using `as.character` on *some* of the objects but not all within the enclosing `c(.)`, so everything is being converted to a `character`; to see what I mean, try `c(as.character(1), 2)`; we can use a `list` instead to preserve string-vs-number

```r
rbindmodelcoeff <- function(modelcoeff, mymodel) {
  summ <- summary(mymodel)
  rbind(modelcoeff,
        list(as.character((summ$terms[[2]])[[3]]),
             as.character((((((summ$terms[[2]])[[2]])[[3]])[[3]])[[2]])[[3]]),
             summ$coefficients[2,1],
             summ$coefficients[2,4],
             summ$coefficients[2,2],
             summ$r.squared*100))
}
```

But there are still some problems with this. I can't get it to work at the moment since I don't know the model parameters you're using, so `as.character((summ$terms[[2]])[[3]])` for me will fail. With that, I'm always hesitant to hard-code so many brackets without a firm understanding of what is being used. It's out of scope for this question (which is being converting your basic code into a function), but you might want to find out how to generalize that portion a bit.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. The suggestion to replace summary(mymodel) is also very helpful. The coefficients refer to the summary of a simple linear model lm() and the character objects are 1. the dependent variable and 2. the group variable. So both are strings. Using the brackets was for me the only way to extract these strings from the linear model summary.